# Chart js shows old chart data when hover

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was having some trouble with doughnut chart by using chart.js. The problem is when I update the graph, and when I hover over the graph, sometimes it shows the old chart. Here is where I call the function to plot chart:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlCategory" onchange="plotChart()">     
</select>

function plotChart(){
// removed code to retrieve data from firebase
var chart;
var ctx = document.getElementById('donutChart').getContext("2d");
var data = {};
var opt = {
          type: "doughnut",
          data: data,
          options: options
        };

        if (chart) {
            chart.destroy();
            chart.clear();
        }else{
            chart = new Chart(ctx,opt);
        }
for(var i = 0; i < labelData.length; i++){
        chart.config.data.labels.push(labelData[i]);
    }
chart.update();
}
```

I tried to destroy the previous chart before I update it but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed need to destroy the previous chart. Perhaps try with the following :

```
function plotChart() {
   // removed code to retrieve data from firebase

   var ctx = document.getElementById('donutChart').getContext("2d");
   var data = {};
   var opt = {
      type: "doughnut",
      data: data,
      options: options
   };

   if (chart) chart.chart.destroy();
   window.chart = new Chart(ctx, opt);

   for (var i = 0; i < labelData.length; i++) {
      chart.config.data.labels.push(labelData[i]);
   }
   chart.update();
}
```

Comment: Where do you declared the myChart variable?

Comment: here > `window.myChart = ...`, you can also declare it outside the function

Comment: I am getting myChart variable is undefined error message. Also, by declaring myChart, does that means my chart.update() should change to myChart.update() also?

Comment: I see but after added your suggested solution, the part where I dynamically populate the chart is getting error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

Comment: I am confused. Do you mind to provide an example on where you actually declared the myChart variable? Is it outside the plotChart() function? Also, if that is the case, the place where I declared chart variable should remains, am I right?

Comment: Nope the problem is still persist. The old chart data is still showing when hovering over

Comment: I see. I shifted out the var chart. Previously I put it inside the function. Now the error message is: TypeError: chart.chart.destroy is not a function.

Comment: which version of chartjs are you using? make sure to use the latest one -
 chart.js v2.6

Comment: I see! That solved the problem. I didn't realized I was using 2.4!

Comment: Cheers !!­­­­­­­

Comment: Hey do you mind to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427957/chart-js-only-first-bar-of-bar-chart-is-colored?

Comment: @hyperfkcb @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ What if I have multiple charts on a single page? I am also facing the same issue, but I have multiple charts on a single page. If I destroy the `window.chart` only one chart is displayed because other charts are already destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your *chart* variable is being **redeclared** everytime the function is called and hence will never exist when you call plotchart(). Would recommend that you declare the variable before and bring it into the correct scope if it exists. That seems to be the core of your problem

Comment: So you mean declare the chart variable outside the function? But wouldn't it lead to undeclared variable error?

Comment: as given above make sure you are using the latest version and yes declare it outside