# Chart.js not showing dynamically populated data

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I was having some trouble when trying to dynamically populate bar chart in chart.js. I have two arrays, one for label, one for its price and both of them are already populated with the sorted data from firebase. Here is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('brandChart').getContext("2d");
        
        var data = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#424242",
                ]
            }]
        };
        
        var options = {
            layout: {
                padding: {
                  top: 5
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                // disable legend onclick remove slice
                onClick: null
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            },
        };
        
        var opt = {
          type: "horizontalBar",
          data: data,
          options: options
        };
        
        if (brandChart) brandChart.destroy();
        brandChart = new Chart(ctx, opt);

        // dynamically populate chart
        for(var i = 0; i < labelData.length; i++){
            brandChart.config.data.labels.push(labelData[i]);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < priceData.length; i++){
            brandChart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push(priceData[i]);
        }
                
        brandChart.update();
```

I managed to show all of them in bar chart, however, the result as such:

It is kind of squeeze between each labels if there are too many categories. Also, only the first bar has the color & the legends shown undefined. Any ideas how to solve these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ɪꜱꜱᴜᴇ #1 - ꜱᴏʟᴜᴛɪᴏɴ**

Add a callback for y-axis ticks, in your chart options :

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            callback: function(t, i) {
               if (!(i % 2)) return t;
            }
         }
      }]
   },
   ...
}
```

this will only show every other label on y-axis.

**ɪꜱꜱᴜᴇ #2 - ꜱᴏʟᴜᴛɪᴏɴ**

This is because, you have only one color in your **`backgroundColor`** array. If you want different color for each bar, then you need to populate this array with multiple color values.

<sup>**Edit:** as it seems form your updated question, you already kind of got the idea.</sup>

**ɪꜱꜱᴜᴇ #3 - ꜱᴏʟᴜᴛɪᴏɴ**

Define the **`label`** property for your **`dataset`** , like so :

```
datasets: [{
   label: 'Legend Title', //<- define this
   data: [],
   backgroundColor: ["#424242", ]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But there is nothing shown on the chart for the edited portion. Do you have any ideas why is it so? There is something printed out from the data array, just that nothing was shown on the chart itself

Comment: you are not populating the `data` array properly. think carefully

Comment: Yeah the arr is the array which populated with all the sorted data. Because previously when I retrieved from firebase, the data aren't sorted. After I sorted them all, I store the sorted one into arr variable.